# How to use Matlab function cfirpm with arbitrary frequency grid gf

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to use Matlab function `cfirpm` to design FIR filter with complex impulse response having arbitrary complex desired response. However, it seems Matlab do not allow me to set arbitrary frequency grid `gf`.

Here is a dummy example where frequency grid is initially set to have only four values. However, inside `fresp` function the grid `gf` have 256 values.

```
n = 10;                              
f = [-1 1];                          
gf = linspace(-1,1,4);
h = cfirpm(n,f,@fresp);

function [dh,dw]=fresp(n,f,gf,w)
 dh = [1+1j;1+2j;-6-4j;-8];
 dw = ones(size(gf))
end
```

Am i doing something wrong or `gf` can not be set to arbitrary values?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gf is not a parameter over which the user has direct control: cfirpm generates gf internally, interpolating between the points in f according to a 'density' value specified by the optional lgrid parameter.